# Is there a shortcut to minimize just the selected window in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. There is a place in the settings where I can add a shortcut for minimizing all open windows. I was wondering if there is a way to add a shortcut for minimizing just the selected window. Because there isn't such an option in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the current window you can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd>. Alternatively, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you’ve used keyboard shortcuts in Windows since the mid-90s, that second one will be muscle memory